# Layer-backed labels not subpixel antialiased anymore in 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, nstextfield

In OS X 10.10 Yosemite layer-backed labels (`NSTextField`s) are not subpixel antialiased anymore. This was working just fine in Mavericks. When layer-backing is disabled it works. This is just the case when there is no background color.

I couldn't find any hints in the documentation or release notes.

What can be done?

Comment: I also just ran into this, reviving an old Xcode project of mine. Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: @Pripyat I don't think so, no... It's less of an issue now with the retina displays though.